# What is a practical use case for this function?

Tags: scala

What is a practical use case of this function :

```
def functionMonoid[A,B](B : Monoid[B]) : Monoid[A => B] = 
    new Monoid[A => B] {
        def op(f : A => B, g : A => B) = a => B.op(f(a) , g(a))
        val zero: A => B = a => B.zero
    }
```

This is taken from book "Functional Programming in Scala" .

So

```
val intAddition = new Monoid[Int] {
    def op(a1 : Int, a2 : Int) = a1 + a2
    val zero = 0
}
functionMonoid(intAddition)
```

produces type : `Monoid[A => Int]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one example that's a little closer to a "practical use case". Suppose we've got some kind of request type:

```
case class Request(...)
```

We've also got some kind of `Item` that can be displayed on a web page or some other UI:

```
case class Item(...)
```

And we've got some methods that produce items from requests:

```
def userItems(req: Request): List[Item] = ???
def postItems(req: Request): List[Item] = ???
def adItems(req: Request): List[Item] = ???
```

We want to run a request through these methods and aggregate these results. We can write this:

```
def allItems(req: Request) = userItems(req) ++ postItems(req) ++ adItems(req)
```

Or we could use `functionMonoid` to put a `Monoid[Request => List[Item]]` in scope and then write this:

```
val allItems = List(userItems _, postItems _, adItems _).suml
```

Is this better? Not necessarily, but it's more generic and if you add a few more requirements that could become valuable.